# External IP check reports different IP from /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: debian, networking

My ISP gave me static ip range for internet access: 123.123.123.120-125

(Debian) /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 123.123.123.120
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 123.123.123.254
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

When I go to an external website to check my ip address, it does not report 123.123.123.120, in fact exernal ip check shows me 23.23.23.45 which is different from what the ISP gave me. I can still access internet normally though. (Traceroute shows 23.23.23.45 is also owned by my ISP)

The Windows machine right beside this Linux machine is setup using 123.123.123.125, and the website exernal ip check shows 123.123.123.125

I suspect that the ISP is using some kind of advanced proxy? Is it possible that only the Linux machine recognizes the real IP but not Windows?

So I did another test, I setup a Windows machine and used same ip 123.123.123.120, I unplugged ethernet cable from Linux machine to Windows machine, run ip check and the ip check reports correctly, it reports 123.123.123.120.

What is causing this weird phenomenon in the Linux machine?

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

**Note: *eth0 and eth2 are for virtualbox virtual nics to bridge to so I just commented it out and left them alone*

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

## eth0 TPLink Realtek
# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet static
# address 10.10.10.10
# netmask 255.0.0.0

# eth1 mobo intel nic
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 61.xx.yy.zz
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 61.xx.yy.254
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

## eth2 intel nic
# auto eth2
# iface eth2 inet static
# address 10.10.20.20
# netmask 255.0.0.0
```

and my ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:f3:c1:00:52:50  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe00:5250/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13885 (13.5 KiB)  TX bytes:14304 (13.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x4000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:a7:a0:bb  
          inet addr:61.xx.yy.zz  Bcast:61.xx.yy.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3285:a9ff:fea7:a0bb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:339 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:53807 (52.5 KiB)  TX bytes:23917 (23.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:39:1f:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:fe39:1fe1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:643 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:72405 (70.7 KiB)  TX bytes:43037 (42.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7dc0000-f7de0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with ping and traceroute along with tcpdump in both directions - from your linux box to an external node and back.
Try e.g. https://www.whatismyip.com/ ... with HTTPS, not HTTP.
And ... ask the ISP if there is any address transalation or (http) proxy. :)

EDIT: Perhaps your browser is being (automatically) configured to use a proxy. Check with e.g. `tcpdump -i eth1 port 80` to see if your browser is talking directly to the destination server or not.

Comment: There definitely is address transalation or (http) proxy going on. I don't want to go down the path of having the ISP bend to my request, instead, I think I should explore how to make (Debian)/etc/network/interfaces emulate Windows' NIC configuration.. ugh, worst case I might have to change server to Windows just to make this bug go away.

Comment: If it really is your ISP forcing http through a proxy, then it would be the same for Linux and Windows. I guess you need to investigate a bit more. Try https and try with http again, but use wget tool both on Linux and on windows. If you have access to a web server log (on an external server) - use it to check again. Your eth1 config is fine. how are the other interfaces configured? eth0? What does ifconfig say on the linux box?

Comment: added interfaces and ifconfig to question

Comment: Yes, I tried https and http, same results 123.123.123.120 reports 23.23.23.45. Though I had another Linux machine connect with 123.123.123.120 and ip check reported 123.123.123.120 back. So this is not a problem with Linux. Since the only difference between Linux#1 machine and Linux#2 machine is motherboard and installation of Virtualbox. I hardly think Virtualbox would cause something like this so probably the motherboard is causing this issue on a hardware level?

Comment: What happens if you use "123.123.123.121" or "123.123.123.125" on the Linux box? Did you try using wget? Perhaps your browser is being (automatically) configured to use a proxy. Check with `tcpdump` on the Linux box: does your web browser talk to the destination web server directly?

Comment: If I use 123.123.123.120, 121, 122... it reports only one IP back: 23.23.23.45, I rebooted also just to make sure everything gets cleared.

Comment: I don't have the command `tcpdump`, where can I find it?

Comment: Inserting a simple router in front of NIC1 fixes the ip check problem. I changed NIC1 to dhcp and allow the router to be gateway. Router WAN Static ip = 123.123.123.120 and whatismyip.org reports 123.123.123.120 from Linux machine browser. Odd eh?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I can think of that would produce such symptoms is some automatic configuration of the HTTP client to use a proxy. If it includes HTTPS, it would be a SOCKS proxy. Use the package manager of your distribution to install tcpdump and other tools. For Debian, Ubuntu and similar it's `apt-get install tcpdump`.